Issue with Turkish Characters in Filtered Options after Applying Uppercase Transformation in PrimeNG Dropdown
I am working with the PrimeNG Dropdown component in my Angular project. The Dropdown component is used to display a list of options, and I am transforming the labels to uppercase before applying the filter. However, I am facing an issue with Turkish characters (like uppercase "İ") after converting the text to uppercase. These characters are not correctly handled during the filtering process.
while working
not working properly
please, help this problem
existing code below
<p-dropdown id="mudurlukId" [options]="mudurlukOptions" formControlName="mudurlukId"
                    appDropdownTurkishFilter filterLocale="tr"
                    [filter]="true" filterBy="label"  (onChange)="onChangeMudurluk($event)"></p-dropdown>

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdownTurkishFilter]'
})
export class DropdownFilterDirective {
  private originalOptions: any[] = [];

  constructor(
    private dropdown: Dropdown,
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  @HostListener('onFilter', ['$event'])
  onFilter(event: any): void {
    if (!this.originalOptions.length) {
      this.originalOptions = [...this.dropdown.options];
    }
    const filterValue = event.filter.toLocaleUpperCase('tr-TR');
    const filtered = this.dropdown.options.filter((option: any) => {
      const normalizedLabel = option.label.toLocaleUpperCase('tr-TR');
      return normalizedLabel.includes(filterValue);
    });

    this.dropdown.options = [...filtered];
    console.log("this.dropdown2",this.dropdown.options); // options is true filtered
    console.log("this.dropdown2",this.dropdown);
  }

}
